# Relationship between Nullspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m*n$ matrix, and let $A'$ be an $m'*n$ matrix. Is there a relationship between:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\begin{pmatrix}A\\A'\end{pmatrix}$ is well-defined only if $A$ and $A'$ have the same number of columns.

Back to your question, we have 
$$N\begin{pmatrix}A\\A'\end{pmatrix}=N(A)\cap N(A').$$
This follows from the following obersation:
$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\A'\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix}Ax\\A'x\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$N\begin{pmatrix}A\\A'\end{pmatrix}=N(A)\cap N(A').$$

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the case. Is this directly from the definition of nullspace?

Comment: Directly: $\; \begin{pmatrix}A\\A'\end{pmatrix}$ represents the linear map $f\colon\mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R^{n+n'}=\mathbf R^n\times\mathbf R^{n'}$ defined by $$f(x)= \begin{pmatrix}Ax\\A'x\end{pmatrix}.$$